# Javascript Guess list on prompt

Tags: javascript

What JavaScript element do we use to get a guess list like Google has it while typing in their search box

The following is the code I have now:

```
function callWebsiteByName(website) {
    var location = document.querySelector(".linker");
    if(website) {
        location.innerHTML = "https://www." + website + ".com";
    } else {
        this.website = prompt("What website would like to go", "google");
    }

    location.setAttribute("href", "https://www." + website + ".com");
    return location;
}

callWebsiteByName();
```

Comment: [<datalist>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist), though it's quite limited and you might want to look for a library implementing dropdown autocomplete.

Comment: you mean typeahead? there is no native element for that. you can find typeahead or autocomplete dropdowns in multiple frameworks such a bootsrtrap, but it its not supported out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for helping to both of you, then will look for google library

Comment: except <datalist> its not easy to make autocomplete dropdown using javascript?